# DbContext is empty using EF6

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I used *Visual Studio 2013* to generate the model from an existing database. The model is generated and I was able to add few entries to the database using this model. However, whenever I try to read from the DB all entries are returned as null.

I'm using this code:

```
using (MaintenanceDB db = new MaintenanceDB())
{
    try
    {
        var data = from e in db.employees select e;
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = data;                        
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

the variable `data` is empty and nothing is appearing in the datagrid. I tried to use the debugger to check this in the **Count property** is 0

I tried using:

```
db.employees.Find("H1992");
```

In this case I can find the wanted entry. But it only appears in the datagrid if I used `db.employees.Local`

Comment: `data` is only the query. If you want to access items you will have to materialize the query with  `ToList()` for instance. Anyway I don't get the point why you use a linq statement either? Furthermore - what is `db.employees.Local?

Comment: yeah sorry I edited this by mistake
it should be dataGrid.ItemsSource = data;

but what do you mean it's only the query?

Comment: I updated your question as of your comment. I am not quite sure why you use LINQ - there is no need for it. You could direclty assign `dataGrid.ItemsSource = db.employees;` Did you try this? For a detailed explanation on LINQ see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb397926.aspx)

Comment: Actually yes I tried this and the datagrid is even emptier! and by emptier I mean not even coulmen names, anyways I added ToArray() to the linq query and the data is there in the grid now thanks! add it as answer if u want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is only the query. If you want to access items you will have to **materialize the query** with `ToList()` or `ToArray()` for instance.

Anyway I don't get the point why you use a linq statement either - there is no need for it!

You could direclty assign `dataGrid.ItemsSource = db.employees;` Please see **MSDN** for a detailed explanation on [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb397926.aspx).